# PromQL over HTTP is not returning any result over curl

Tags: prometheus

when PromQL URL is invoked on chrome browser, the response is returned. but, when the same URL is executed using curl in command prompt no response is returned. also, the same behavior was observed using java code with RestTemplate. please help me with this!

here is the sample URL executed.

```
curl http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=up&time=2021-08-06T07:23:35.781Z
```

[image]
[image]
Thanks,
Raja

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your browser knows how to encode the URL so that it conforms to the rules in the [respective spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986/). If you're using `curl`, you need to take care of that yourself, for example:

```
curl -s -G \
     --data-urlencode "query=up" \
     --data-urlencode "time=2021-08-06T07:23:35.781Z" \
     "http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query"
```

Comment: still not working this for me - I got `{"status":"success","data":{"resultType":"vector","result":[]}}` however via browser it is ok; that is what browser is doing with the url: `https://localhost/api/v1/query?query=container_memory_working_set_bytes{pod=~%22.*402-adc-access.*%22}`